# Different sentences similiar to "what ... about"

Tags: prepositions, wh-questions

The context is from Forbes on youtube.

Around at 06:24 [How To Ace Your Job Interview Over Zoom | Forbes](https://youtu.be/Si4GLeQoqLA?t=384)

A sentence:

> You need to know what you want them to understand about you.

what does this sentence really mean?

Is it like

> You need to know something about you and you want them to understand that thing.

Also I am not sure about the usage of  `about`.

Suppose a document is about you.

> Ask: What is it about?

**Meaning**: What is this document about?

> Reply: You.

**Meaning**: The document could be about a house, a room or a dog...

Another ask: What is it about you?

**Meaning**: It could be a recording or a video about you.

Reply:The document.

Is my understanding correct?

Please shed light on my doubt.

thanks

Comment: It's impossible to say exactly what it means without context, but it seems that 'you' are about to do something which will give other people an idea of the sort of person you are.   The speaker says that you need to decide what impression you want to give these people.

Comment: @KateBunting The context is from Forbes on youtube. Around at 06:24 [How To Ace Your Job Interview Over Zoom | Forbes] [1]   [1]: https://youtu.be/Si4GLeQoqLA?t=384

Comment: Then it does mean what I suggested. You need to decide what impression you intend to give the interviewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original quote was:

> You need to know what you want them to understand about you.

The sentence shown above is grammatically correct. However, I can see why it would seem confusing. Let us explain some things.

The following two words have meanings similar to "Understand":

> - "know"
> - "comprehend"
> - "learn"

Suppose you wrote,

> Jack wants to understand.
> Sarah wants to know.
> My daughter wants to learn.
> The interviewer wants to understand.

What do they want to understand?
What do they want to know more about?

The words "know" and "understand" are almost always followed by "how to" or "about"

- Jack wants to ***understand*** how to bake a cake
- Jill wants to ***understand*** more ***about*** how elephants migrate
- Fred wants to ***understand*** more about how to make furniture out of wood.

Many people are unsure about what they want to give to a future employer.

The quote was:

> You need to know what you want them to understand about you.

So,

> - There are facts about you.
> - Some facts will help you get the job.
> - You need to know which facts you want a job interviewer to have.
> - What information will help an interviewer understand more about you?

Comment: Wow, the description you gave is very vivid and casts light on the question. Now, I can easily see the picture in my mind. Fantastic!